# Airflow doesn't send all the metrics by statsD

Tags: airflow, statsd

I have enabled the statsD monitoring in airflow.cfg

```
[metrics]
# StatsD (https://github.com/etsy/statsd) integration settings.
# Enables sending metrics to StatsD.
statsd_on = True
statsd_host = localhost
statsd_port = 8125
statsd_prefix = airflow
```

Added the mapping file from https://github.com/databand-ai/airflow-dashboards/blob/main/statsd/statsd.conf
But I am getting few warnings -

```
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.814Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.dag_processing.processes
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.814Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.scheduler.critical_section_busy
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.814Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.dag.callback_exceptions
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.814Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.celery.task_timeout_error
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.814Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.dag_processing.import_errors
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.814Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.dag_processing.total_parse_time
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.814Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.dag_processing.processor_timeouts
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.814Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.executor.open_slots
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.814Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.executor.queued_tasks
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.814Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.executor.running_tasks
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.smart_sensor_operator.poked_tasks
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.smart_sensor_operator.poked_success
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.smart_sensor_operator.poked_exception
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.smart_sensor_operator.exception_failures
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.smart_sensor_operator.infra_failures
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.scheduler.critical_section_duration
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.scheduler.tasks.killed_externally
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.scheduler.tasks.running
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.scheduler.tasks.starving
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.scheduler.orphaned_tasks.cleared
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.scheduler.orphaned_tasks.adopted
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.dag_processing.last_runtime.*
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.pool.open_slots.*
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.pool.queued_slots.*
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.pool.running_slots.*
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.pool.starving_tasks.*
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.dagrun.dependency-check.*
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.dag_processing.last_duration.*
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.dagrun.schedule_delay.*
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.dagrun.*.first_task_scheduling_delay
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.ti.start.*.*
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.dag_processing.last_run.seconds_ago.*
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.dag.*.*.duration
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.dagrun.duration.success.*
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.dagrun.duration.failed.*
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.ti_failures
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.ti_successes
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.zombies_killed
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.scheduler_heartbeat
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.sla_email_notification_failure
ts=2022-11-05T09:22:24.815Z caller=fsm.go:314 level=warn msg="backtracking required because of match. Performance may be degraded" match=*.dagbag_size
```

I am not getting these metrics wherever there is a warning message while I am getting other metrics.
Running airflow with celery executor v. 2.3.0
statsd_exporter, version 0.22.8

Running this command - **./statsd_exporter --statsd.listen-udp=":8125" --statsd.listen-tcp=":8125" --statsd.mapping-config="/tmp/statsd_exporter-0.22.8.linux-arm64/statsd_mapping.yml"** and expecting to receive all the metrics once I enable the statsD monitoring.